# Remove access control for only signup page - symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, access-control

My access control field in **security.yml** looks like

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

That means I want to control access for every page on the app. So if anyone trying to access

```
http://localhost/example/web/app_dev.php/
```

will be redirected to login page. But my signup page is also there. Login page contains a Signup button. So when I redirect someone to signup page, it triggers access control and redirect to the same login page. That means

```
http://localhost/example/web/app_dev.php/signup
```

this can't be accessed.

How can I allow user to access only signup page and not any other pages??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use exclusion pattern like **(?!exclude)**

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/(?!signup), roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But as for symfony2, signup page you must to exclude at firewall config:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/(?!signup)
        anonymous: false
        form_login:
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /
            check_path: /auth_check
            login_path: /signup/
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /signup/

access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```